# updating in triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table `Prescription_Medicine` that has `ID`, `NumOfDrug`, and `numOfUnit` columns.

I want to write a trigger that if `numOfUnit` is less than zero, the program sets it automatically back to 1.

Here is what I have tried, but it is wrong.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('trigger2_9', 'TR') is not null
    DROP trigger trigger2_9;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trigger2_9 ON Prescription_Medicine
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS ( select Prescription_Medicine.NumOfUnits
            from Prescription_Medicine
            JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON Prescription_Medicine.NumOfUnits = i.NumOfUnits
            group by Prescription_Medicine.NumOfUnits
            having  Prescription_Medicine.NumOfUnits <= 0
          )
BEGIN

    alter table Prescription_Medicin
    update Prescription_Medicin
        set inserted.numOfUnits = 1;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
```

What should I do!?

Answer (score 1):

Your `update` needs to update a table, not `inserted`.  Also, the syntax for `update` doesn't involve `alter table` (which often isn't allowed in triggers anyway).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('trigger2_9', 'TR') is not null
    DROP trigger trigger2_9;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trigger2_9 ON Prescription_Medicine
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( select pm.NumOfUnits
                from Prescription_Medicine pm JOIN
                     inserted AS i 
                     on pm.NumOfUnits = i.NumOfUnits
                group by pm.NumOfUnits
                having pm.NumOfUnits <= 0
              )
    BEGIN
        update Prescription_Medicin
            set numOfUnits = 1;
    END;

END;
```

However, I wonder if you could do what you want with "check" constraints and computed columns.

Comment: I executed this code and I see it makes all tuples of numOfunits equal to zero. I just one that one who is less than zero becomes 1

Comment: @user2178942 . . . I kept your logic, only fixing the syntax errors.  I suspect the solution from NoDisplayName does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Trigger` like this. There is no need of `Alter Statement` in a Trigger to `update` a table which makes no sense.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM   inserted 
           WHERE  numofunits <= 0) 
  UPDATE A 
  SET    numOfUnits = 1 
  FROM   prescription_medicin A 
         JOIN inserted I 
           ON A.id = PM.id 
  WHERE  i.numofunits <= 0
```

Considering that `ID` is an Identity Column

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to 'alter table...'

That statement is used when you are changing the definition of the table itself (I.e adding or dropping a column).